# Read SharePoint online lists from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, odata, sharepoint-online, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to read data from a list in the SharePoint online, using Azure Data Factory. It should be possible using OData. I'm struggling to authenticate from ADF.

From Chrome I can access the list data without problems using URL like this:

https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyListName

I have account name that can read the list, and its password. I'm struggling with authentication in ADF. I tried basic and windows, with no success. For the others, I do not know what to set...

Short step by step instructions of how to read a SharePoint online list in ADF is highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the process of writing out how to do so in a MSDN thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85ab91ef-0336-4832-b750-2ed007b030a9/access-sharepoint-list-data-using-adf?forum=AzureDataFactory